# Skip multi tests in Xcode

Tags: swift, xcode, unit-testing, testing, xctest

I'm writing unit tests in my Swift app.

I have tests that i want to skip over, using the flag `shouldSkip`, something like -

```
if shouldSkip {
     throw XCTSkip()
}
```

The problem is -
I don't want all the tests to have to write this line over and over + all the skipped test needs to be marked as "skipped" (the gray arrow, NOT pass or fail).

So I thought about override `invokeTest` or using the `setup` to skip all the tests when the flag in `true`, something like -

```
override func setUp() {
        
        if shouldSkip {
          throw XCTSkip()
        } 
        super.setUp()
}
```

but i couldn't make the tests to be marked as skipped (only pass or fail)

Any ideas on how to skip (and mark as skipped) a bulk of tests (in the same file or not)?

I know about test plans and schemes but i need the tests to run and be skipped in oppose to not running the tests.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to throw the `XCTSkip`, since it is an `Error`, simply creating it has no effect on your test outcome.

Or you can use the `XCTSkipIf` function, which skips the test in case the passed in condition is met.

So in the tests you want to skip, just call `XCTSkipIf(shouldSkip)`. Or if you want to avoid having to write it in all tests, you can do it in `setUpWithError`, which is the throwing variant of `setup`.

Instead of doing  `if shouldSkip { XCTSkip() }`, the correct approach is either `XCTSkipIf(shouldSkip)` or `if shouldSkip { throw XCTSkip() }`.

Using one of these 2 solutions will correctly mark the tests as skipped.

For more info, see the [Methods for Skipping Tests](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xctest/methods_for_skipping_tests) doc page.

Comment: But I can't use `try` inside `invokeTest()` or `setup()`...

Comment: @ozd there is a throwing variant of `setup`, called `setUpWithError()`, you need to use that to be able to throw from it. For `invokeTest`, you're right, you cannot throw from it. However, as I've said (and as the documentation clearly states), you __need to throw__ if you want a test to be marked as skipped, so `invokeTest` is simply not the right function to skip your tests from.

Comment: OOOOO, I missed `setUpWithError()` I was trying to use `invokeTest()`! So this is great! About the **throw** part, I was actually using it, so I edited my question to say **throw** because this was not the problem I was trying to solve. can you please edit your answer to also talk about "use `setUpWithError()'  with throw " so I can accept it?

Comment: +1 for `try XCTSkipIf(true, "Disabled until TICKET-1234")` instead of just `throw XCTSkip(…)`. With the simpler `throw XCTSkip("…message…")`, Swift's compiler detects the remainder of `setupWithError` will never be run and will warn about it. Using `XCTSkipIf(…)` prevents this compile time analysis, so no warning is produced.